# How to open a drop-down list after cell click

Tags: extjs, combobox

I have a combobox editor in my Name column.  Now when I click on a cell, cell becomes active and after that when I click on the trigger, I get a dropdown list.
I have "clicksToEdit: 1", but I still have to click one more time to get the dropdown list

Can I make it so that when I click on a cell, a drop-down list appears immediately?
I mean, the drop-down list should appear without additionally clicking on the trigger. Immediately after activating the cell
Is that possible? please help

**This my fiddle** https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/3cn9

*P.S. Pardon my English.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add a focus listener for the combobox and call there the *expand* function.

```
{
    header: 'Name',
    dataIndex: 'name',
    flex: 1,
    editor: {
        xtype: 'combobox',
        editable: false,
        queryMode: 'local',
        displayField: 'name',
        triggerAction: 'all',
        valueField: 'name',
        store: names,
        listeners: {
            focus: function (item) {
                item.expand();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I extended your fiddle:
https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/3cng

Another possibility would be the a listener for the cellediting plugin, but here you have to analyze the correct cell and editor and handle it accordingly. I think the focus listener of the combobox ist the easiest way.